# Drupal - Webform element theming

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-webform

Another question about Drupal webforms --
The form itself is built in by */includes/form.inc*'s

**`function theme_form_element($element, $value)`**

and adds a `<label>` element to the $output. I want to remove that label only for one webform, so I have to override the function.
How can I override it for only one webform, while leaving it the same in all others?
E.g.

```
if ($block == 'contact'):
  // only output <input> form element stored in $value
  function mytheme_html_form_element($element, $value) {
    $t = get_t();
    $output .= " $value\n";
    return $output;
  }
endif;
```

Is this possible, and what goes in the if condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did have to do a hook_form_alter, but the label itself was in the ['submitted'] element.
here is the code

```
  if($form_id == 'webform_client_form_18') {
    $form['submitted']['#children'] = '
    <input
     type="text" 
     maxlength="128"
     name="submitted[email]"
     id="edit-submitted-email"
     value="' . $form['submitted']['email']['#default_value']. '"
     class="form-text required"
    />
  ';
  }
```

in a different form, removing the #title worked (+1 for you!), but this was a different case.

Answer (score 6):

If you're just looking to remove the label, you can also use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6), and check that $form_id is equal to the webform in question. The id will be of the form: webform_client_form_N where N is the node ID of the webform.

Once you're operating on the proper form, you can unset the label using, for example, code like this:

```
 unset($form['submitted']['first_name']['#title']);
```

Which would unset the label for a field called first_name.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't unset form element titles. You could get unexpected results when your form gets rendered by the theme engine.

You can do it several ways:

Theme each element or the whole form with with `'#theme' => 'my_callback'`.

You can also create your own form element using hook_elements that uses a corresponding theme hook.

See:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_elements/6